# Run JavaScript in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: javascript, aptana3

I used Aptana Studio 3 for Python, and when I hit the "Run", the results are shown in the the console. However, when I created js file and then hit "Run", it opens up my firefox browser and show the codes there, not even the results. Why is that?

Comment: Because that's the typical JavaScript developer requirements - to see how their code works in a browser. Try that with a .html file. (Better editors do a better job at this, and Aptana can too).

Comment: So if I type `alert ("hello world")` in a js file, I won't be able to see the output of `hello world` in the console? Sorry newbie here :P

Comment: `alert` is not a part of JavaScript but rather a part of an API that glues JavaScript to the browser. In serverside JavaScript ( NodeJS for example) `alert` does not even exist.

Answer (score 0):

It seems impossible according to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418292/is-there-a-way-to-run-javascript-code-inside-aptana-studio-3-ide). However, you can use node.js. Simply call `node myFile.js` to run it (after installation). Another solution is embedding scripts in an html file.

Well, for node.js :
Go on their site : http://nodejs.org, and download it. After that, reboot and in eclipse, select `Run > External Tools... > External Configuration.`
Then put :

```
Location : node

Working directory: ${container_loc}

Arguments: ${resource_loc}
```

[image]
See this thread : [Custom command for Eclipse on current file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369983/custom-command-for-eclipse-on-current-file). Also note that the command `alert`does not work since it is cli.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with embedding the script in html and it worked. I will check out node.js as well.